# Try to add in different views to a single page, keep getting "Error" message?

Tags: views, panels, debugging

I have a panel where I'm pulling in 7 different views pages in different regions, and when I try and save it, I keep getting the same message-- "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

So, I went to the specifics of the error and this is what it says:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'panel' at row 1: INSERT INTO {panels_pane} (did, panel, type, subtype, shown, access, configuration, cache, style, css, extras, position, locks, uuid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 41 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => block_layout_row_2_col_2_row_1_region_1_ [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => views [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => review_entries [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => a:15:{s:23:"override_pager_settings";i:1;s:9:"use_pager";i:0;s:14:"nodes_per_page";s:1:"5";s:8:"pager_id";s:1:"0";s:6:"offset";s:1:"0";s:9:"more_link";i:1;s:10:"feed_icons";i:0;s:10:"panel_args";i:0;s:12:"link_to_view";i:1;s:4:"args";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:0:"";s:7:"display";s:7:"block_6";s:14:"override_title";i:0;s:19:"override_title_text";s:0:"";s:22:"override_title_heading";s:2:"h2";} [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => a:1:{s:8:"settings";N;} [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_13] => cc38c8a0-a223-4b16-91ca-7426f802c8f8 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7308 of /srv/bindings/2ed870ecae69481598cc782d3c4e9589/code/includes/common.inc).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?? Thanks!

Comment: The machine name "block_layout_row_2_col_2_row_1_region_1_" apparently is too long. Can you try without this pane to see if works? And if do, try to remake the views with a shorter machine name.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the data for some columns is too long. I had the same problem in some where else, so I simply opened the phpmyadmin, found the column and change it's type to something else with more capacity. In my case the type was `blob` and I changed it to the `long blob` and it worked.

Try this and I guess it will work

Comment: I thought that might be the case, so I deleted all of the views on my page, and simply kept the layout of columns, rows, and regions with one custom text block, and still when I tried to save the page I got an error

Comment: Did you change the column type?

Answer (score 0):

The Machine-Name of the panel ("block_layout_row_2_col_2_row_1_region_1_") is too long (40 characters), as it is defined by as varchar(32). I guess it comes form your blocks machine name. You may name the block different, to get a shorter name. I had a similar problem with a view display name, where the subtype gots to long so I had to choose a shorter display machine name.